# Can't load assets ressources (css + js) in production with Rails 6

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

When I start my application in production mode the assets (css + js) don't load correctly.

I get in browser's console `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` or in Rails log `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application-51bdb73d26ac893c3407.js"):`

I made `rake assets:precompile` and also turned `config.assets.compile = true` in environments/production.rb but same result

For the production mode I used the same app and the same directory I just add `-e production` as argument to the `rails server` command

Comment: I'm getting same exact error right now. Tried bunch of thing, but couldn't figure out. I'm using rails 6.0.3. I have some sense that can be my problem but anyway I will be watching this question

Comment: You need to be more exact here in order for us to be able to help you. Where did you precompile the assets? Locally? On the production server? Did you deploy the files to the production server? What are the exact steps that we can take to reproduce the issue? Please edit and clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you should set `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` environment variable to `true`

Suggestion is based on this [issue comment](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1249#issuecomment-447154510) I found while resolving same trouble

This only affects configuration at `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same, Fixes of it was a bit different as below-

1. Step 1-
   Run `rake assets:clobber.` to reset everything and delete all compiled assets from public/assets dir.
2. Compile assets-
   Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` which regenerate all assets(CSS, JS, Images).
3. Change ownership-
   Change owner of public/assets with `chown login_user:login_user public/assets`

Root Cause-

> App was running on *login_user* but public/assets dir having root access.

Above approach saved my day!!